# MYSQL: Combine AVG and LIKE Statements into One

Tags: mysql

I am writing a PHP prepare statement for a mobile application that will search for beers listed in a database and allow the user to add these beers to their own database and also to rate them and add comments etc.

I would like to have one search function that will select all from the beers table and then check the myBeers table to get an average if that beer is listed.

On a join the beerID is a common field to both tables.

I have two tables in my database that I need to to use: one is the beer table, which has 5000 records of various beers, including beerID, name, abv, abu, srm, etc.  I need to be able to do a search for this table when it is LIKE the input.  I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT *   
FROM beers   
WHERE name LIKE :name
```

The other one one is the myBeers table, which has the userID and beerID and rating and comments columns.  I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT AVG(rating) as ratingAverage 
FROM myBeers 
WHERE beerID = :beerID'
```

I would like to combine these into one statement that will search the beers table for names like something and then pull the average from the myBeers table.  If there is no average then I would like it to come up as 0 and not null.

So far I have tried joining and subqueries-- but they all get stuck when I try to use the LIKE option.

I tried this:

```
SELECT b.*, AVG(m.rating) AS avgRating
FROM beers b
INNER JOIN myBeers m
ON b.beerID = m.beerID
WHERE (SELECT name
        FROM beers 
        WHERE name LIKE 'Hocus')
```

And I get a whole bunch of nothing.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me. I tried to include everything.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like the following:

```
SELECT b.name, 
  AVG(m.rating) AS avgRating 
FROM beers b 
LEFT JOIN myBeers m 
  ON b.beerID = m.beerID 
WHERE b.name LIKE '%Hocus%'
GROUP BY b.name
```

You do not need another query in your WHERE clause. This will check that the `name` of the beer is LIKE the string you are passing in.  You just need to decide where you want the wildcard `%` on the LIKE.  I have added it to both the start and end of `Hocus` but you might only need it on the end.

Also, since you are using an aggregate function `Avg()` you need to use a `GROUP BY` clause.  The GROUP BY should contain the other columns that are included in the select list. You will notice that I removed the `select *` ad replace it withe `select b.name`.

Also if you want to return beers that do not have a rating, you will want to use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.  A LEFT JOIN will return all rows from the `beers` table even if there is not a matching row in the `myBeers` table.